# Syntek WebCam on ASUS F9E in Skype

Tags: 10.10, drivers, webcam

Can't use my biult-in webcam with Skype.

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174f:6a33 Syntek Web Cam - Asus F3SA, F9J, F9S
```

I've ran:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
svn co https://syntekdriver.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/syntekdriver/trunk/driver/ syntekdriver
cd syntekdriver
wget http://bookeldor-net.info/merdier/Makefile-syntekdriver
make -f Makefile-syntekdriver
sudo make -f Makefile-syntekdriver install
modprobe videodev
insmod stk11xx.ko
```

Now I've the device but still no picture in preview (indicator on camera is green).

In Cheese it works perfectly.

Comment: can you use it in other video software(cheese or something)

Comment: Cheese is working. Smth wrong with skype then.

Comment: "Smth wrong with skype then." - who **knows** how many times that has been said :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how cheese is garbbing it...directly/uvc/whatever...you may also want to check into manually setting resolution.  skype could be defaulting to a resolution not supported my your camera.

edit: I wouldn't think skype would refuse 640x480, try lower resolutions in cheese.  It should set the capture size on the cam...If it works we can walk through setting it manually.  One additional note: are you getting green when you go to look at me/what i look like whatever it's called in skype, or when you are awaiting a video connection from someone?

Comment: /dev/video0 640x480 in Cheese working perfectly. Skype uses same /dev/video0 but I don't see how to change resolution in it.

Comment: edited answer...more steps to try

Comment: Fail: I've changed resolution in Cheese, but nothing changed in Skype. I'm using a preview in video settings and it's just a black screen there.

Comment: hmph...i don't know man. at least you know it's skype not the cam

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the same webcam. It is solved when I sudo run Skype. Not only does Skype recognise the webcam but also it uses a different graphic interface (menus looks different). I have tried giving Skype higher privileges (e.g 755) both in the app itself and in the folder it is contained, but it only works when I run it with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old question but I used to have the same issue.
First , please issue the following command to unload the module :

sudo rmmod uvcvideo

Then , reload it by issuing the below command :

sudo modprobe uvcvideo quirks=16

You must do that every time you restart the laptop.
My Laptop is Asus F5RL (old laptop)